# How can I output the matching portion of two strings, while having the % character separate any non-consecutively matching portions?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I was hoping I could get some help on a project I've been working on. Given two strings, I would like to output the matching portions of these strings. Further, I would like any non-consecutive portions of the match output to be separated by the `%` symbol.

For example, if my two string inputs were:

- `This is a test case see if it works` and
- `test case it hopefully works`

Then my desired output would be:

- `test case%it%works`

EDIT:
I have written how I would like the code to be structured, but need some help fine-tuning the exact syntax, any help would be really appreciated. Here is how I think it could be done:

```
string1 = A1 cell
string2 = B1 cell
output = ""
counter = 0
if LENGTH(string1) < LENGTH(string2) then split_string=string1 and other_string=string2             '
ELSE split_string=string2 and other_string=string1
matchable_values=split(split_string)
for each element in matchable_values      
    if ISNUMBER(SEARCH(element, other_string,counter)) then 
       output = output & element & %   and counter = counter + 
       LENGTH(element) + 1
     ELSEIF counter = counter + LENGTH(element) + 1
next element

return output
```

Comment: I am not sure what's your question, at the moment it looks like you asking us to do your homework. Show us what you have tried so far, and then formulate a proper question, something better than "how do I do this".

Comment: Annoying test case for you:  `"What output if this works?"` and `"What if this output works?"`

Comment: @Chronocidal ^^ For your interest: There are actually algorithms to solve that too. Obviously there will be more than one result possible and you need some good scoring to evaluate which one is the best (the one with the less changes, probably). Actually this task is at an advanced level ... have a look below.

Comment: @Ssr1369 I've updated my question now to add some more detail and work I've done on the subject

Comment: @Chronocidal based on the algorithm I've outlined above, the output would be "What%if%this%works?%", which is good enough for the task I will be using it for

Comment: `string1 A1 cell` can be written in many ways, for example: `string1 = [A1].Value` or `string1 = Range("A1").Value` or `string1 = Cells(1,1).Value`.  To return values, read up on [the `Function` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement)

Answer (score 7):

What you try is not easy to accomplish, and you would need some advanced development skills (basic knowledge in [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) is extremly useful).

What you try to do is actually the same idea as aligning DNA sequences in bio informatics.

---

So what you would need to do is take both of your strings (sequences)

```html
This is a test case, see if it works
test case, it hopefully works
```

and align them for example using the [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) (there are more known algorithms to do alignments):

```html
This is a test case, see if it ----------works
----------test case, -------it hopefully works
```

Then check which characters are the same, so the result would be …

```html
----------test case, -------it ----------works
```

And then replace the multiple dashes with `%` while removing dashes from the end and beginning. So your final result would be:

```html
test case, %it %works
```

Note that for your issue there does not exist one definive result. There will always be more results possible! If you do alignments there may be different ways to align 2 sequences.

---

So the Needleman Wunsch backtracing for the alignment above would look something like that:

[image]

---

#### Why there is no simple solution for that?

For example we take the following 2 strings:

```html
What output if this works?
What if this output works?
```

They can be aligned (wordwise) as

```html
What output if this        works?
What        if this output works?
```

or as

```html
What         output if this works?
What if this output         works?
```

So there are 2 results

```html
What % if this % works?
What % output % works?
```

and they are different. Other strings might have even more than 2 possible results.

So you need an algorithm that can give you **all** the possible results and then you need an algorithm to determine which one is the best one (the one you want to have). In the case above how would you tell which one of the 2 results is the right one?  … you can't :)

---

To give you another example:

We use the following 2 strings

```html
to proove you wrong this is a good example for you
is this a good example to proove you wrong
```

can be aligned (at least) as follows:

```html
                       to prove you wrong this is a good example for you
is this a good example to prove you wrong


to prove you wrong this is a good example for you
                        is                        this a good example to prove you wrong

   to prove you wrong this is a good example          for you
is                    this    a good example to prove     you wrong
```

and you will get these 3 (or even more) results:

```html
% to proove you wrong %
% is %
% this % a good example % you %
```

Would you be fine if your algorithm picks the second result for you? Or would you expect something different? All 3 are valid results.

But you are probably looking for the best one, and we can get this by counting the gap words.

[image]

The result with the less gap words is the best. So you see that the second is the worst one and the last one is the best one. But to be able to evaluate this we need to use an algorithm that is able to find **all** results in the first step, so we can evaluate which one of them is the best one.

Comment: Nice explaination. I wonder if something can be done rather simple by two `Split` arrays and its items their relative position towards eachother

Comment: @JvdV I bet if there was a simpler solution bioinformatics would use that :) What you suggest is probably the same issue to solve. Just that you do it word wise instead of character wise (which would shorten the runtime of the algorithm). What you suggest *"their items and their relative position to each other"* is exactly what the algorithm does.

Comment: @JvdV It can be done by a split data array and in compare to the other data, something like this, A1: "This is a test case, see if it works", A2 :"test case, it hopefully works"  and In B1 enter array formula (CSE) : =SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("%",TRUE,TRIM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")&" "," "&A2&" "))," "&FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")&" ",""))),"%"," ",1) and the result is : "test case,%it%works" ( the formula only work for Office 365 for the using of TEXTJOIN function)

Comment: @bosco_yip but this will produce a strange result for `What output if this works?` and `What if this output works?` you will get `What output%if%this%works?` which actually should be `What output%if this%works?` (which has less substitutes).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thank you for your notes, but I don't think it doesn't need to be as complicated as you've outlined here, please see the edit I've added which provides a potential solution

Comment: @bosco_yip I was on the same thought process as you, if you have a look at my edit I think I have a way it can be done :)

Comment: @JvdV yes I think found a solution but need some help fine-tuning the syntax, please have a look at the code I added via edit

Comment: @skimo Basically your issue is the same as aligning DNA sequences. So if there was a simple solution for that then the guys using bioniformatics would have used it (unless you are able to revolutionize sequence aligning, which I assume you are not going to). Your approach might output "something" that is working for your example but not in general (for other strings) as I tried to explain the mechanism is much more complicated than you think and than you can develope with one example.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I don''t need it to work for all strings. It will be run on strings that have 90%+ similarity in their names (as found via fuzzy lookup). For that reason I believe although what you're saying is true, for my use case a simpler solution does in fact exist

Comment: @skimo There is no simple solution as because of the reason I added to my answer.