# Comparing 2 column ranges

Tags: excel, vba, strikethrough

I want to compare two strings/columns in excel. column A has old comments while column B has new comments. Final output is to get column C with old text strikethrough and new added text in red color. If there is no change/difference in column A & B then show text as it is in column C.

Also included VBA code that I have tried. Image 1 is what I need as a final output. Image 2 is what I have achived so far using the VBA.

Please provide inputs on how can I achieve it. Also any comments on improving the post/question are welcome. Appreciate it !

Image 1:
[image: Scenario]

Image 2:
[image]

```
    Sub highlight()
    Dim xRg1 As Range, xRg2 As Range, xRg3 As Range
    Dim xCell1 As Range, xCell2 As Range, xCell3 As Range
    Dim xTxt As String, I As Long, J As Integer, xLen As Integer
    Dim xDiffs As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
        xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
        Else
        xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If

lOne:
    Set xRg1 = Application.InputBox("Range A:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If xRg1.Columns.Count > 1 Or xRg1.Areas.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Multiple ranges or columns have been selected ", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    GoTo lOne
    End If
lTwo:
    Set xRg2 = Application.InputBox("Range B:", "Kutools for Excel", "", , , , , 8)
    If xRg2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If xRg2.Columns.Count > 1 Or xRg2.Areas.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Multiple ranges or columns have been selected ", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    GoTo lTwo
    End If

'lThree:
'   Set xRg3 = Application.InputBox("Range C:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)


    If xRg1.CountLarge <> xRg2.CountLarge Then
    MsgBox "Two selected ranges must have the same numbers of cells ", _
            vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    GoTo lTwo
    End If

    xDiffs = (MsgBox("Click Yes to highlight similarities, click No to highlight differences ", _
                vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Kutools for Excel") = vbNo)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xRg2.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic

    For I = 1 To xRg1.Count
        Set xCell1 = xRg1.Cells(I)
        Set xCell2 = xRg2.Cells(I)
        Set xCell3 = xRg3.Cells(I)
        If xCell1.Value2 = xCell2.Value2 Then
            If Not xDiffs Then xCell2.Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
            xLen = Len(xCell2.Value2)
            For J = 1 To xLen
                If Not xCell1.Characters(J, 1).Text = xCell2.Characters(J, 1).Text Then Exit For
            Next J
            If Not xDiffs Then
                If J <= Len(xCell2.Value2) And J > 1 Then
                xCell2.Characters(1, J - 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                xCell3.Value = xCell2.Characters(1, J - 1)
                End If
            Else
                If J <= Len(xCell2.Value2) Then
                xCell2.Characters(J, Len(xCell2.Value2) - J + 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                xCell3.Value = xCell2.Characters(J, Len(xCell2.Value2) - J + 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next


    For I = 1 To xRg1.Count
        Set xCell1 = xRg1.Cells(I)
        Set xCell2 = xRg2.Cells(I)
        If xCell1.Value2 = xCell2.Value2 Then
            If Not xDiffs Then xCell2.Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
            xLen = Len(xCell1.Value2)
                For J = 1 To xLen
                    If Not xCell1.Characters(J, 1).Text = xCell2.Characters(J, 1).Text Then Exit For
                Next J
            If Not xDiffs Then
                If J <= Len(xCell1.Value2) And J > 1 Then
                k = xLen - J
                xCell1.Characters(1, k).Font.Strikethrough = True
                End If
            Else
                If J <= Len(xCell1.Value2) Then
                xCell1.Characters(J, k).Font.Strikethrough = True
                'xCell1.Characters(J, Len(xCell2.Value2) - J + 1).Font.Strikethrough = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Actually what you are asking for is probably a way more complicated as you see for now. Also your example does not reflect the issue you can run into very well: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628570/how-can-i-output-the-matching-portion-of-two-strings-while-having-the-charact/58628990#58628990) that I wrote for a similar question. I'm especially referring to the last example series there, that shows that there is actually no simple answer. • At least not unless you define a very precise and smart rule how to work with cases where multiple possibilites exist.

Comment: See if [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/243417/compare-text-in-two-excel-ranges-highlighting-additions-and-strikethrough-delet) helps.. As this question is closed, could not post answer here.